# How to universally rename something the same?

Tags: animation, rigging, unreal-engine

Okay if you use UE4 you know very well it is a very difficult-to-use engine. I have now run into another issue. I was under the impression if the bones were in the right hierarchy, named proper, etc UE4 was happy with using that skeleton for whatever objects you have it rigged for. Turns out no. I was wondering if there is a way to universally rename these, all the same, without numbers being added? (This is what UE4 requires now) [image]

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, All game engines like Unity and Unreal need you to rename them properly because that is how it makes it easier for the engine and you to create your game. If you don't do so, in the long run, you will face more issues. So the answer to your question is unfortunately, no. And next time, don't use offensive language.

Comment: That sucks. Yeah I know of the pedantic ways but this is asinine. I only read the name the bones, keep the hierarchy the same everywhere I read but once I imported it oh boy was I in for the typical unreal experience. Man this is some bull. I am going to have thousands of models. This is going to be hell.

Comment: I agree with you. This is actually a lot of work and isn't normally worth it. It's like paying for 1000 dollar pizza and getting a 2 dollar pizza. But no 3d software has such options, so we have to rename them ourselves.

Comment: Well I guess I will grab the whiskey, and get started lol. I hate that Blender renamed everything with 1 and so on behind it sad panda I am.

Comment: Please, don't use offensive language like hell. This is against the rules of the stack exchange and you could be blocked from stack exchange if you keep using this sort of language. Also, I am a 12-year-old so you have to be a bit careful with talking with me.

Comment: Okay I'm done here then. I kept my language at TV level. I am not playing human any lower. Screw this. I am not walking on egg shells. Surprised there is no auto censor sites do it all the time. but if this site is going to be this pedantic I am not writing anymore. I will figure this out on my own. It isn't worth trying to play human that far. Not walking on eggshells. Ciao.

Comment: I didn't want to offend you or anything. I just told you the rules of this site. I did it for your own good, 'cuz if you kept continuing this, someone could have seen your comments and could have reported you and you could've been banned from this site.

Comment: Well I am as good as banned as is. I cannot play human well. Thanks for the heads up though I now know how asinine this place is. I would say on par with UE4 community if it is that bad. Sad but whatevs. I say play human because I have some disorders that make it hard to bring it down to a low level. I have to actually stop and think about each step and that is annoying. If TV language is not good enough then screw it.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't know that. I seriously don't mind TV language, but well, I don't make the rules here. I didn't want you to fall into trouble if someone else flags you, that's why I gave you a heads up.

Comment: I have Aspergers so it being human is hard. I do my best but I cannot just be a perfect human. It is hard to walk on eggshells. If this place is that sensitive yeah I am as good as banned though. Nothing I can do about it. Sucks but I really do not care at this point.

Comment: It's okay, it's not like it's your fault. I am surprised you actually replied like after a year, but, it will come wit practice, so there's nothing to worry about.